# How can I change .then function to async/await function?

Tags: node.js, async-await, protractor

I want to pass this function with .then to an async / await function but I can't find the correct way. Here is the function:

```
waitForCssClass = function(cssClass, waitTime) {
    var options = [],
    defer = protractor.promise.defer();
          
    browser.wait(function () {
            element.all(by.className(cssClass)).then(function (displayed) {
              options = displayed;
            }, waitTime);
            return options.length > 0;
          }, waitTime).then(function () {
            defer.fulfill(options);
    });
    
    return defer.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
waitForCssClass = async function(cssClass, waitTime) {
    return browser.wait(
        async () => await element.all(by.className(cssClass)).count() > 0,
        waitTime,
        'message on failure'
    );
};
```